# Why is repaint() not reaching the paintComponent() method?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have been working on a Rotating Line project for AP Java at school. All of the support classes are completely done (by my partner) but I have not yet finished my display because of my `paintComponent()` method not working at all.

I have already asked for help and no one has yet been able to find the error. All I need is to make these polygons paint on the screen and I can do the rest.

Here is what I have so far:

```
imports...

public class Display extends JFrame {


protected int screenHeightD = 600;
protected int screenWidthD = 700;
private ArrayList <Rotator> planesOnBoard = new ArrayList ();
private Timer timer;
private boolean timerOn = true;
private int timerDuration = 300;
private int rotateDegValue = 5;
PlaneFacilitator painter = new PlaneFacilitator();
JFrame display = new JFrame ("Rotating Line");



public class PlaneFacilitator extends JComponent {

    // takes the double arrays sent by the getXArray/getYArray
    public int [] convertXcrds ( double [] xCrdsD ) {

        int [] xCrds = new int[xCrdsD.length];

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < xCrdsD.length - 1; i++) {
            double e = xCrdsD [i];
            xCrds [i] = (int) Math.round (e);
        }
        return xCrds;
    }
    public int [] convertYcrds ( double [] yCrdsD ) {

        int [] yCrds = new int[yCrdsD.length];

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < yCrdsD.length - 1; i++) {
            double e = yCrdsD [i];
            yCrds [i] = (int) Math.round (e);
        }
        return yCrds;
    }

    // paints the entire set of planes
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){

        System.out.println("Painted");
        planesOnBoard.add(0, new Rotator (screenWidthD / 2, screenHeightD / 2, new Dimension (screenHeightD, screenWidthD)));
        planesOnBoard.get(0).addPolygon(Color.black, 1, 0, true);


        for ( Rotator target : planesOnBoard) {

            for ( int polyIndex = 0; polyIndex < target.getNumPolygons(); polyIndex++ ) {

                double[] xCrdsD = target.getXArray(polyIndex);  
                double[] yCrdsD = target.getYArray(polyIndex);

                g.setColor(target.getColor(polyIndex));
                g.drawPolyline(convertXcrds(xCrdsD), convertYcrds(yCrdsD), xCrdsD.length);

            }

            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawRect(target.getXOrigin() - 2, target.getYOrigin() - 2, 5, 5);

        }

    }

}


// ctor for display, creates the frame...
public Display () {

    display.setLayout(null);
    display.setSize(screenWidthD, screenHeightD);
    display.setTitle("Rotating Line");

    display.add(painter);
    System.out.println(screenWidthD + " " + screenHeightD);

    JButton startB = new JButton ("Start");
    JButton pauseB = new JButton ("Pause");

    ActionListener pauseBL = new pauseB();
    pauseB.addActionListener(pauseBL);
    ActionListener startBL = new startB();
    startB.addActionListener(startBL);
    startB.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 20);
    pauseB.setBounds(170, 10, 150, 20);
    display.add(startB);
    display.add(pauseB);

    display.addMouseListener(new DropDownMenuListener());

    display.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    display.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    display.setVisible(true);
    display.setBounds(0, 0, screenWidthD, screenHeightD);
    display.setResizable(false);
    display.getContentPane().repaint();

}   

// creates a dropdown menu that appears whenever you click on the screen.
class DropDownMenu extends JPopupMenu {
    public DropDownMenu(){
        JMenuItem addPent = new JMenuItem ("Add a Pentagon");
        JMenuItem addQuad = new JMenuItem ("Add a Quadrilateral");
        JMenuItem addTri = new JMenuItem ("Add a Triangle");
        JMenuItem addLine = new JMenuItem ("Add a Line");
        JMenuItem reverseRot = new JMenuItem ("Reverse the Rotation of the plane");
        JMenuItem addNewPlane = new JMenuItem ("Add a new plane here");

        add(addPent);
        add(addQuad);
        add(addTri);
        add(addLine);
        add(reverseRot);
        add(addNewPlane);

        addNewPlane.addActionListener(new addPlaneListener());
        addLine.addActionListener(new addLineListener());
        addTri.addActionListener(new addTriListener());
        addQuad.addActionListener(new addQuadListener());
        addPent.addActionListener(new addPentListener());
        reverseRot.addActionListener(new addReverseRotateListener());

    }
}


// Lots an lots of listeners...
int xCrdMenu;
int yCrdMenu;
class DropDownMenuListener extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        if (e.isPopupTrigger())
            xCrdMenu = e.getX();
            yCrdMenu = e.getY();
            doPop(e);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        if (e.isPopupTrigger())
            doPop(e);
    }

    private void doPop(MouseEvent e){
        DropDownMenu menu = new DropDownMenu();
        menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
    }
}

// defines the behavior of the startB
// starts the timer...rotates x degrees each time
class startB implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timerOn = true;

        (timer).scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
        {
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("Time");

                for ( Rotator target : planesOnBoard) {

                    for ( int polyIndex = 0; polyIndex < target.getNumPolygons(); polyIndex++ ) {

                        target.rotate ( rotateDegValue, polyIndex );

                    }

                } painter.repaint();

            }
        }
        , (long) timerDuration, (long) timerDuration); 
    } 

}

// defines the behavior for the pause button
class pauseB implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(timerOn == true){
            System.out.println("Pause");
            timer.cancel();;
            timerOn = false;
        }
    } 
}   

class addPlaneListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //JFrame source = (JFrame) e.getSource();
        Plane added = new Plane (getContentPane().getY(), getContentPane().getX(),getContentPane().getY(),getContentPane().getX());
        planesOnBoard.add(new Rotator (added));
        added.setOrigin(xCrdMenu, yCrdMenu);

        painter.repaint();
        System.out.println("Plane");
    } 
}

class addLineListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        planesOnBoard.get(0).addPolygon( new Polygon (Color.black, 1, 180, true, getContentPane().getY(), getContentPane().getX(),getContentPane().getY(),getContentPane().getX()));
        painter.repaint();
        System.out.println("Line");
    }
}

class addTriListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        planesOnBoard.get(0).addPolygon(Color.black, 3, 60, true);
        painter.repaint();
    }
}

class addQuadListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        planesOnBoard.get(0).addPolygon(Color.black, 4, 90, true);
        painter.repaint();
    }
}

class addPentListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        planesOnBoard.get(0).addPolygon(Color.black, 5, 108, true);
        painter.repaint();
    }
}

class addReverseRotateListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        rotateDegValue *= -1;
    }
}


public static void main ( String [] args ) {

    Display experiment = new Display();

}
}
```

Comment: It may not fix your error, but as a case of good practice, add the `@Override` annotation to the top of overridden methods (Such as `paintComponent`). Also, using a null layout is almost never a good idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be because of this...

```
display.setLayout(null);
```

Basically `painter` has a default size (and location) of `0x0`.  This means that the RepaintManager probably takes a look at and thinks to itself, it would be waste of time painting that, as nothing would show up anyway and discards any repaint requests to.

You should make use of an appropriate layout manager, like `BorderLayout` for example...

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Thank you for your help!